# anchor tag is not appearing in bootstrap options

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, anchor

I am making pagination sorting but the anchor tag is not appearing . When i inspect element there is no anchor tag in the option . I cant understand why this happening. I am using bootstrap. Here is my code

```
 <select class="wide">
    <option data-display="Select">Nothing</option>
    
    <option value="Relevance">
    <a href="shop.php?sort=1">Relevance</a>
    </option>
    
    <option value="Name, A to Z"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?sort=2"; ?>"> Name, A to Z</a>
    </option>
    
    <option value="Name, Z to A"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?sort=3"; ?>">Name, Z to A</a></option>
    
    <option value="Price, low to high">
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?sort=4"; ?>">Price, low to high</a>
    </option>
    
    <option value="Price, high to low"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?sort=5"; ?>">Price, high to low</a></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element allows only text in its content, possibly with escaped characters (*e.g.* `&eacute;`).
You can't add an `<a>` inside, but you can handle the `onclick` event with JavaScript.

Comment: so its means i cant use anchor inside the option

Comment: @Azeez exactly, but if you want you can handle an event when the user clicks on a specific `option` .